# null cannot be cast to non-null type android.support.v4.view.ViewPager - KOTLIN

Tags: android, mobile, kotlin, null, viewpage

I know that these question has been already answered, but I think it's a different deal. So, I have the following code:

```
viewPager = findViewById<View>(R.id.viewPagerGaleria) as ViewPager
val adapter = ViewPageAdapter(this)
viewPager.adapter = adapter
//dots
val pageIndicatorView = findViewById<View>(R.id.pageIndicatorView) as PageIndicatorView
pageIndicatorView.setViewPager(viewPager)
```

And when I run it this occurs: ... kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.support.v4.view.ViewPager. Normal till here, right? No, because when I do this, the error is the same:

```
val viewPager = findViewById<View>(R.id.viewPagerGaleria) as? ViewPager
val adapter = ViewPageAdapter(this)
viewPager?.adapter = adapter
//dots
val pageIndicatorView = findViewById<View>(R.id.pageIndicatorView) as? PageIndicatorView
pageIndicatorView?.setViewPager(viewPager)
```

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that ID is actually in your layout? Also, the type that's inside the `<>` is there so you can specify which View that ID is. `findViewById<View>(R.id.viewPagerGaleria) as ViewPager` can be shortened to `findViewById<ViewPager(R.id.viewPagerGaleria)`.

Comment: @TheWanderer yes sir, it is...

Comment: Are you sure? If `findViewById()` returns null it means it can't find any View by that name. Where are these methods being called and where is `setContentView()` being called? Are you sure you're setting the right layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @TheWanderer, your problem is here :findViewById**** .

So to fix this you can remove the type  and replace it by  and get rid of the cast "as? ViewPager" as it is not needed in this case

```
val viewPager = findViewById<ViewPager?>(R.id.viewPagerGaleria)
```

Or omit the target class type  definitely and keep the cast

```
val viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager) as? ViewPager
```

PS : And you probably don't have the required viewPager id in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry mates, i was putting that code in the wrong class! My bad!